# Як перекласти stakeholder?

Tags: переклад, from-english, терміни

В літературі по інформаційним технологіям **stakeholder** визначається як

> A person, group or organization that has concern in a system

За змістом найбільш підходить *зацікавлена сторона*, проте слово concern має трохи ширше значення ніж зацікавленість. Це і дотикатися, і турбувати, і цікавитися, і стосуватися. Тобто не усі stakeholder можуть бути зацікавлені - деякі можуть бути, наприклад, тільки стурбовані.

Інший варіант - *небайдужа сторона* охоплює більше різних відтінків, та чи доречним буде такий термін в технічному документі?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

«Стейкхолдер» (від англ. Stakeholder) буквально:

«**Власник частки (одержувач відсотка); утримувач закладу**», з самого початку - **розпорядник** (**довірчий власник**) спірного, закладеного або підопічного майна, **пайовик**); у вузькому сенсі слова: те ж, що і shareholder (**акціонер**, **учасник**), тобто особа, яка має частку в статутному (складеному) капіталі підприємства; в широкому сенсі: одна з фізичних або юридичних осіб, зацікавлених у фінансових та інших результати діяльності компанії.

[ЗНАЧЕННЯ ІНТЕРЕСІВ СТЕЙКХОЛДЕРІВ У ПРОЦЕСІ УПРАВЛІННЯ ДІЯЛЬНІСТЮ ПІДПРИЄМСТВА](http://www.rusnauka.com/18_DNI_2010/Economics/69677.doc.htm)

[Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%86%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%96_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8) дає **зацікавлена сторона**, також **зацікавлена особа**, **заінтересована сторона**, **причетна сторона**.